# Showing expression of $dA$ in cartesian coordinates = $dA$ in cylindrical polar

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cylindrical-coordinates, curvilinear-coordinates

In cartesian coordinates, $dA = dx\,dy$ .
As $x=\rho \cos\phi\ $ and $y=\rho \sin \phi \ $,

then: $dx=  \cos\phi\, d\rho - \rho \sin\phi\, d\phi$ and $dy = \sin\phi\, d\rho + \rho \cos\phi \, d \phi  $.

So $dx\, dy = \rho\, d\rho\, d\phi(\cos^2\phi-\sin^2\phi) $, (ignoring second order terms in $d\rho$ and $d\phi$)

Why is this not equal to the correct result of $dA=\rho\, d\rho\, d\phi$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $d\rho\, d\phi=-d\phi\, d\rho$

Comment: I did not know the multiplication of differentials was not commutative, is there any reason for this being so?

Comment: It is actually an *exterior product* (i.e. an alternating  product) $\;\mathrm d\rho\wedge\mathrm d\phi=-\mathrm d\phi\wedge\mathrm d\rho$, $\mathrm d\rho\wedge\mathrm \rho=0$, &c.

Comment: Yes it is from the defintion of the exterior product, and for the same reason $d\rho \wedge d\rho =-d\rho \wedge d\rho=0$